# How to use Event delegation instead of attaching an event listener to every single item individually?

Tags: javascript

How to convert this code into event delegation?

This is HTML code

```
<ul id="todo-app">
  <li class="item">Walk the dog</li>
  <li class="item">Pay bills</li>
  <li class="item">Make dinner</li>
  <li class="item">Code for one hour</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let app = document.getElementById('todo-app');
  let items = app.getElementsByClassName('item');

  // attach event listener to each item
  for (let item of items) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('you clicked on item: ' + item.innerHTML);
    });
  }

});
```

Above code technically work, the problem is that, attaching an event listener to every single item individually. 
Using above code application could end up with hundreds of event listeners, the more efficient solution would be to actually attach one event listener to the whole container, and then be able to access each item when it’s actually clicked.

So , how to make this code using event delegation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to know to achieve what you want in pure Js is in this post [Event Delegation - David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

In your case would be:

```js
document.getElementById("todo-app").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
 // e.target was the clicked element
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("li.item")) {
    console.log("List item clicked!");
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="todo-app">
  <li class="item">Walk the dog</li>
  <li class="item">Pay bills</li>
  <li class="item">Make dinner</li>
  <li class="item">Code for one hour</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

how about this, binding event on `ul`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let app = document.getElementById('todo-app');
  let items = app.getElementsByClassName('item');

  app.onclick = function(e){
    alert('you clicked on item: ' + e.target.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="todo-app">
  <li class="item">Walk the dog</li>
  <li class="item">Pay bills</li>
  <li class="item">Make dinner</li>
  <li class="item">Code for one hour</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is really comfortable to use for event delegation situation. You just have to attach your listener to the parent element, and specify the child type element on which the event will be delegated :

```js
    $( "#todo-app" ).on( "click", "li", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log( $( this ).text() );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="todo-app">
  <li class="item">Walk the dog</li>
  <li class="item">Pay bills</li>
  <li class="item">Make dinner</li>
  <li class="item">Code for one hour</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions with libraries or languages that have neither been tagged nor mentioned in the question - unless OP states they are open to new libraries being introduced